# Viewing the value of an element in litElement

Tags: javascript, polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I have a very simple element that wrap an `<input type="range">` element.
Coming from Polymer, I am having a bit of a hard time adjusting.
I want to display the value of the range.

This is what I came up with:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element'

class InputRange extends LitElement {
  static get properties () {
    return {
      shownValue: {
        type: String,
        attribute: false
      }
    }
  }

  firstUpdated () {
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#native').value)
    this.shownValue = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#native').value
  }

  render () {
    return html`
      <input value="10" @change=${this.updateShownValue} type="range" id="native">
      <span>VALUE: ${this.shownValue}</span>
              `
  }

  updateShownValue (e) {
    this.shownValue = e.srcElement.value
    console.log(e.srcElement.value)
    // e.srcElement.value = 80
  }
}
window.customElements.define('input-range', InputRange)
```

And then using it:

```
    <script type="module" src="./InputRange.js"></script>
    <h2>Range</h2>
    <input-range id="input-range"></input-range>
```

Question:

Is this the right way of doing it? lit-element's documentation states clearly *During an update, only the parts of the DOM that change are re-rendered. To get the performance benefits of this model, you should design your element’s template as a pure function of its properties.* But does that mean that I necessarily need to 1) set `shownValue` at fistUpdated() 2) listen to the `change` event for it and update `shownValue` accordingly? If that is the case, am I doing it right? Or, is there a better way of doing it?

I have a glitch for it: https://glitch.com/~busy-sternum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do only some minor adjustments

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element'

class InputRange extends LitElement {
  static get properties () {
    return {
      shownValue: {
        type: String,
        attribute: false
      }
    }
  }

  constructor () {
    this.shownValue = 10;
  }

  render () {
    return html`
      <input value="${this.shownValue}" @change=${this.updateShownValue} type="range" id="native">
      <span>VALUE: ${this.shownValue}</span>
              `
  }

  updateShownValue (e) {
    this.shownValue = e.srcElement.value
    console.log(e.srcElement.value)
  }

  anotherFunction () {
      this.shownValue = 80;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('input-range', InputRange)
```

Comment: Thanks for validating my idea